# How to add Linux servers to SolarWinds via Puppet?

Tags: linux, puppet, monitoring

We use Puppet for configuration management. We also use SolarWinds for monitoring.

Has anyone had any experience in adding a server to SolarWinds automatically via Puppet? How did you go about it (e.g., what did you do on the Puppet side and on the SolarWinds side)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Solarwinds, but if SW has an API, one possible way is to use that API in a custom [Puppet Report processor](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/reporting.html). The report processor can check if the host already exists in SW, if not create a new entry.

Instead of the reports level, you can do the same thing in your External nodes script, if you use the ENC feature.